# Is it possible to combine several template files togather and make single integrated template instead?

Tags: theming, 8, forms, blocks

For example to render a simple form like *search block* should be invoked 8 different templates like below and each of this template only has one or few line of code, see below:

```
region.html.twig
└─ block.html.twig
   └─ form.html.twig
      ├─ form-element.html.twig
      |  ├─ form-element-label.html.twig
      |  └─ input.html.twig
      └─ container.html.twig
          └─ input.html.twig
```

As you can see in below some of this files Just have a few line of code:
**region.html.twig**

```
{% if content %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

**form.html.twig**

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>
```

**form-element.html.twig**

```
{% if title is not empty or required -%}
  <label{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ title }}</label>
{%- endif %}
```

**input.html.twig**

```
<input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}
```

**container.html.twig**

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ children }}</div>
```

- Some of this templates files are common with other parts of page and
  editing each of them can affect to other parts and cause unwanted changes
  . for example in this case drupal theme system for: "input.html.twig", suggest only `input--submit.html.twig` and this suggestion also common between `search block` and `search form`.
- Editing and managing this template files is tedious and difficult and
  make my theme folder busy.
- Most of these templates have ambiguity and unclear content code

For this reason I'm looking for a method to combine this template files and make one template file like "`form--search-block.html.twig`" to I can edit all element needs for rendering a form in one special place 
and with more flexibility and confidently.

Comment: Sure you can (I don't know why you'd want to do that though), you have to define your own custom preprocess in your template and remove any dependencies to the prior parent theme and build up your own twig file and name it whatever you want

Comment: @Sohail: Thank's for your help and replay, Can you give me more explain or any reference?

Comment: Technically, yes. Practical? No. Also it doesn't take 8 templates to render the _search form_, it is a chain of things involved in rendering each piece of the page.

Comment: @Kevin: Thank you so much, I'll be very happy if you share and present your technically solution.

Answer (score 2):

In drupal 8 there's this rule called theme inheritance and backward compatibility, what you have to do to accomplish what you want is to make sure that your subtheme does not inherit any core theme's `HOOKS`

You might want to play around in your subtheme and set your base theme to `null`
I haven't checked it myself but it might work.

And then of course you have to define new preprocess templating rules in your `themename.theme` file using `theme_suggestions_page_alter` function, you can read more [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x)

Then based on what you defined in your `.theme` file you may proceed with creating a unified template file

Also you might want to read [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2702061) suggestion that somewhat explains a similar use case

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, I appreciate you a lot, But in this case I can't get any idea or feasible solution from those references, I'm looking for a practical solution. I will be glad to have more cooperation and become more familiar with you in future.

Comment: The thing is Mojtaba, what you want to do is so not useful that kind of breaks the whole concept of Drupal and the way it works, so people don't really ever tried to accomplish this before, so there's no real practical reference for it, unless you want to dig into it yourself which will take quite some time, anyhow if you ever tried to make this happen it would be nice to get an update from you, good luck